# How to convert my Java project into a Desktop Application?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans-8

I have created a Java Project which I want to convert into a proper Desktop application so that it can be run without any IDE. I used Netbeans 8.0.2 to make my Java Project. How can I run it on any computer that doesn't have Netbeans?

Also I have used MySQL connectivity. So, will those databases carry with the project?

Comment: You need to convert it into a jar file. Then it can be run via the java program.

Comment: Right click the project node, select "Clean and Build", wait.  When it's complete, go to the project directory, look in the `dist` directory, copy the contents to where ever you want and double click the `{project_name}.jar` to execute it

Comment: [Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) [How to Generate JAR File in Netbeans](http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-JAR-File-in-Netbeans)

Comment: But can the .jar file be run in a computer which doesn't have netbeans installed?

Comment: I think you can make the file .jar.. it's the same as exe in windows, but the others computers required java to run that.

Answer (score 0):

First, Create Executable JAR File
- By Creating a Project with Existing Sources,
- By Configuring the Project,
- By Building the Project and Creating the JAR File.
Second, Running and Distributing the JAR File.
Third, Starting Your Java Application.
Atlast, Packaging the Application for Java Web Start.